# Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS

Tags: java, spring-boot, email

I have a problem with sending email in my spring boot app. It was working propertly earlier, i didn't change anything in the email sending code and now I'm getting this error when i'm trying to send an email:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2155)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:517)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:436)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:322)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:311)
    at com.capgemini.capdevice.services.email.EmailServiceImpl.simpleEmail(EmailServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.capgemini.capdevice.listener.EmailListener.listener(EmailListener.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1903)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:626)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:553)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:82)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:783)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:77)
    ... 36 more
```

my properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=XXX
spring.mail.password=XXX
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Does anyone know what can cause the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Googling this error returns quite a lot of hits but some are quite old so it looks to me it could depend on what java version you are using.

Comment: I'm using Java 8, the strangest thing is that it worked, and without changing anything it stopped working.